# Looking for Java binary for Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, zimbra

I'm trying to build zimbra from source on a mac mini running on mac os x 10.4.10.

It seems that I need a file like this "jdk-1_5_0_16-linux-i586.bin" but I can't seem to find a jdk binary that is made for mac osx.

Can anybody point me to this binary?

Here is what zimbra does with the binary:

```
sh jdk-1_5_0_15-linux-amd64.bin 

tar czf jdk1.5.0_15.tgz jdk1.5.0_15 

mv jdk1.5.0_15.tgz /opt/build.zimbra/source/FRANKLIN/ThirdPartyBuilds/x86_64/java/
```

If I cannot download this, Is there a way to create the tgz from an installation of java?

Comment: With the little that I understand, I believe I am supposed to install this at the "jdk1.5.0_15" directory, this directory is then tarred to create "jdk1.5.0_15.tgz" which is the one that I need.

Comment: After a lot of searching I was able to find that the JDK is stored in "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions" just tarred this and I got what I needed! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching I was able to find that the JDK is stored in "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions" just tarred this and I got what I needed! Thanks for the help. this is for 10.4, I don't know with previous or the most current version.

Answer (score 3):

Java is part of the Max OS X install. The JDK for Mac is maintained by Apple, and you cannot download it anywhere else.

You should have JDK 1.5 already. Open a terminal and try "java -version" and "which java".

As for Zimbra, their download page has Mac binaries. They should work "out of the box". Are you sure you need to build from source?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to modify zimbra.

Comment: Do you mean "java -version", rather than "java --version"?

Answer (score 0):

- The version of the jdk isntalled on Mac OS X 10.5 is 1.6. I am not sure what is the latest version 10.4 but check on the Apple website because they are the ones that supply the JVM for Mac OS X
- The line `sh jdk-1_5_0_15-linux-amd64.bin` is running a shell script. What is in that shell script? Can you read the shell script and tell us what it is supposed to do. We can only guess from the name. My guess is that it installs the 1.5 jdk which you don't need to do. But that is only a guess
- Regarding your last question. Can you make an tgz of an installation? Why do you want to do that? I ask because if you are trying to do what the three lines you quoted are doing then all it looks like it is doing is installing the jkd which you can already do by getting the Apple JDK installer.

Comment: With the little that I understand, I believe I am supposed to install this at the "jdk1.5.0_15" directory, this directory is then tarred to create "jdk1.5.0_15.tgz" which is the one that I need.